# Parameter passing in ProcessBuilder returns "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, parameter-passing, processbuilder

I have the following code which builds my java command and runs process builder.

```
String runCommand[] = {"java", ExerciseSelected + " " + Input};
runpb   = new ProcessBuilder(runCommand);  
Process runp = runpb.start();
```

Input is a string of input separated by spaces. Currently I have an input of 100 which I am passing to my java program.

When running this it returns "Could not find or load main class Exercise 100"

Now i looked at another StackOverflow article that explains how to create a java command call. The command call to processbuilder looks like this

java Exercise 100

If I go to my java application folder and run this same call to the same Exercise.class it works from the command prompt. But it won't work from ProcessBuilder.

I have tried to enclose 100 in quotes and that also did not work. Is it possible there is something I have missed in putting together this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively trying to run

```
java "Exercise 100"
```

You want *two* arguments: "Exercise" and "100", so you should have them as different elements in the array:

```
String[] runCommand = { "java", exerciseSelected, input };
```

Note that if `input` is actually "1 2 3" this will be equivalent to running:

```
java Exercise "1 2 3"
```

which still may not be what you want. You may want to split `input` by spaces first.

(I've adjusted the variable names and the location of the `[]` to be more idiomatic.)

Comment: I have also tried a new method over a plain array to use an ArrayList since ProcessBuilder also reads an ArrayList. It makes adding multiple input a lot easier.

Comment: @DaveK: Yes, that would make it simpler.